# class as an element in an object

Tags: javascript, json

hi
I am trying to read html to get some data from yahoo stock, and I want to read what the class is. so here is what I have

data.query.results.span[0].strong.class

my problem is javascript doesn't like class there and takes it as a special key word or something

when I do data.query.results.span[0].strong.content it works fine.

Strong has 2 elements inside  first class second content.

is there a way to make java look at class as in element in that json object rather than a keyword?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

```
data.query.results.span[0].strong['class']
```

`class` is a reserved future keyword, and will bomb out in most modern browsers now. I know Safari doesn't like it.